# Reshaping polygons while preserving area

Tags: polygon, editing, area, software-recommendations

I'm looking to manually skew the shapes of areal polygons, but need to ensure their areas are not altered.

Is anyone aware of any GIS tools or programming workflows that exist for manually reshaping spatial polygons while preserving areas?

I wonder if there is an approach that utilises anything like the force-directed algorithms used in graph drawing.

Comment: Do you use a specific software?

Comment: I'm pretty flexible. Preferably non-proprietary although ArcGIS is ok.

Comment: Please amplify on the meaning of "manually skew": solutions can range from area-preserving linear transformations (each of which is easy to implement, but with only three degrees of freedom) to arbitrary area-preserving homeomorphisms (or ambient homotopies, perhaps), which have infinitely many degrees of freedom (but may be difficult to implement). What kinds of properties do you wish to change during these transformations and what properties must be preserved (if any) in addition to area?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the variety of approaches so its difficult to be specific. I just need to examine ways to warp/compress/bend/stretch/etc geometric shapes (in whatever data format works) while maintaining area. I'll explore any solutions or toolkits that anyone can recommend. My web search turned up nothing useful but my search terms may've omitted key terms. Cheers.

Comment: The most general way is to warp the feature *any way you like* and afterwards rescale it to match its original area. That is too much freedom for most applications, which is why I am encouraging you to share with us any constraints you would like to impose on the warping process or the resulting shapes.

Comment: Nice question! I was about to ask essentially the same: **Is there any tool or smart way to get support in drawing irregular "areas of interest" of a pre-defined extent?** Ideally, start with a basic shape (say square or rectangle) of a pre-defined area extent (e.g. 25sqkm), then use something like QGIS' excellent _Reshape Features_ tool and, while, modifying the shape at will, other sides of the shape will increase or decrease so as to maintain the predefined area restriction.

Comment: @whuber Is there any practical implementation of the "rescaling" idea?

Comment: @Nikos Sure, plenty.  Rescaling is one form of affine transformation, making it a key tool for registering geographic data.  It can be used to enforce area constraints, as suggested in my previous comment, without changing the actual shape of a figure: rescaling merely changes the size.

Comment: @whuber Right, the well known affine transformation. I'll try to give it a test-drive, not very soon though. Thank you.

Comment: @whuber, Fortunately for GFOSSers, QGIS has a plugin for that (coded by Mauricio de Paulo) called... well [Affine Transformations](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAffine/) :-)

Comment: I'd like to test these suggestions and demo the workflow, but no time right now.  Happy to close off now if people would prefer.